# How to select a specific DMA CHANNEL in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, dma

As part of the development of a device driver, I need to use a specific DMA channel.

The easy way out is to call dma_request_channel passing a dma_filter_funnction that selects the right channel.

The piece of device tree I'm referring to is:

```
        srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA0: dma@48000000 {
            #dma-cells = <1>;
            clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_mm2s_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
            clocks = <&clkc 15>, <&clkc 16>, <&clkc 16>, <&clkc 16>;
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-7.1", "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
            interrupt-names = "mm2s_introut", "s2mm_introut";
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <0 30 4 0 29 4>;
            reg = <0x48000000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,include-sg ;
            xlnx,sg-include-stscntrl-strm ;
            xlnx,sg-length-width = <0x17>;
            dma-channel@48000000 {                       
                compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-mm2s-channel";  // <--- I want select this DMA channel
                dma-channels = <0x1>;
                interrupts = <0 30 4>;
                xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
                xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
                xlnx,include-dre ;
            };
            dma-channel@48000030 {
                compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
                dma-channels = <0x1>;
                interrupts = <0 29 4>;
                xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
                xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
                xlnx,include-dre ;
            };
        };
```

I want to write a dma_filter_funnction which returns true only for
the dma channel named *dma-channel@48000000* which have to be recognized because
the 'compatible' field contains the string **"axi-dma-mm2s-channel"**

I called dma_request_channel like this:

```
    dma_cap_mask_t      dma_cap_mask;

    dma_cap_zero(dma_cap_mask);
    dma_cap_set(DMA_SLAVE, dma_cap_mask);

    slave_dma_chan = dma_request_channel(dma_cap_mask, dma_filter_funnction, ptrToMyData);
```

while dma_filter_funnction is defined as follows:

```
static bool dma_filter_funnction (struct dma_chan *chan, void *filter_param)
{
    struct MyData* myData = (struct MyData*) filter_param;

    struct device*          dev                 = chan->device->dev;
    struct device_node*     device_tree_node    = dev->of_node;

    if (0 != strcmp(device_tree_node->full_name, "dma@48000000"))
      return false;


//  HELP MI: how can I write get_compatible function which get the current
//           channel a and returns a pointer to the compatible attribute value?

    return (null != strstr( "axi-dma-mm2s-channel", get_compatible(chan)));

}
```

Is there anyone who can help me write the get_compatible function: I don't
know how to retrieve the compatible attribute value from the current dma_chan

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide DMA channel names (see other Device Tree excerpts in the kernel) and use respective call, i.e. `dma_request_chan()`.

Comment: I tried to use dma_request_chan(struct device *dev, const char *name) passing as parameter "dev" the pointer returned by bus_find_device_by_name(&platform_bus_type, NULL, "48000000.dma") and as "name" each of the following strings: "48000000. dma-channel", "48000000", "dma-channel@48000000", "axidma0" and "dma1chan0". In all these situations dma_request_chan returns the value 0xffffffed which corresponds to the error pointer ERR_PTR(-ENODEV).

Comment: Checking the code [link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/drivers/dma/dmaengine.c#L806) I understand that this value is set on line 820 and no longer modified because dma_filter_match (line 836) always returns null because the "filter" field of dma_device is null.
I believe correct that of_dma_request_slave_channel returns an error pointer because there is no "dmas" and "dma-names" property in the device tree.

Comment: However, I think it is right that these properties are not present in the device tree because they are mandatory only for DMA clients [link](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-wear-5.0.2_r0.1/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/dma/dma.txt) while dma@48000000 is a DMA controller.

Comment: What youi are trying to do (according to your question) is to request DMA channel for the **consumer**. And I explained in the first comment how to do that properly.

Comment: Of cource you will get that error since you are doing something wrong. The `dev` parameter should be device pointer of the instance of the **consumer**. Hence consumer's piece of Device Tree has to have the phandle to DMA channels and their respective names. Calling `bus_find_device_by_name()` is completely wrong. I suggest you to read in-kernel Documentation regarding DMA Engine subsystem.

Comment: Your own device's node in the device tree needs properties like `dmas = <&srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA0 0>;` and `dma-names = "mydmachan";`. Then you can request the channel named "mydmachan".

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions of 0andriy and Ian Abbott (whom I thank) I solved the problem object of this question in the following way.

I modified the initial Device tree as follows:

```
    srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA0: dma@48000000 {
    #dma-cells = <1>;
    clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_mm2s_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
    clocks = <&clkc 15>, <&clkc 16>, <&clkc 16>, <&clkc 16>;
    compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-7.1", "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
    interrupt-names = "mm2s_introut", "s2mm_introut";
    interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
    interrupts = <0 30 4 0 29 4>;
    reg = <0x48000000 0x10000>;
    xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;
    xlnx,include-sg ;
    xlnx,sg-include-stscntrl-strm ;
    xlnx,sg-length-width = <0x17>;
    dma-channel@48000000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-mm2s-channel";
        dma-channels = <0x1>;
        interrupts = <0 30 4>;
        xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
        xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
        xlnx,include-dre ;
    };
    dma-channel@48000030 {
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
        dma-channels = <0x1>;
        interrupts = <0 29 4>;
        xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
        xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
        xlnx,include-dre ;
    };
};
srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA1: dma@48010000 {
    #dma-cells = <1>;
    ... omissis ...
    dma-channel@48010000 {
        ... omissis ...
    };
    dma-channel@48010030 {
        ... omissis ...
    };
};
srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0: axi_mcdma@48020000 {
    #dma-cells = <1>;
    clock-names = "s_axi_aclk", "s_axi_lite_aclk";
    clocks = <&clkc 16>, <&clkc 15>;
    compatible = "xlnx,axi-mcdma-1.1", "xlnx,axi-mcdma-1.00.a";
    interrupt-names = "s2mm_ch1_introut", "s2mm_ch2_introut", "s2mm_ch3_introut", "s2mm_ch4_introut", "s2mm_ch5_introut", "s2mm_ch6_introut", "s2mm_ch7_introut", "s2mm_ch8_introut";
    interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
    interrupts = <0 36 4 0 52 4 0 53 4 0 54 4 0 55 4 0 56 4 0 57 4 0 58 4>;
    reg = <0x48020000 0x10000>;
    xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;
    xlnx,dlytmr-resolution = <0x7d>;
    xlnx,enable-single-intr = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group1-mm2s = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group1-s2mm = <0xa98ac7>;
    xlnx,group2-mm2s = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group2-s2mm = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group3-mm2s = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group3-s2mm = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group4-mm2s = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group4-s2mm = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group5-mm2s = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group5-s2mm = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group6-mm2s = <0x0>;
    xlnx,group6-s2mm = <0x0>;
    xlnx,include-mm2s = <0x0>;
    xlnx,include-mm2s-dre = <0x0>;
    xlnx,include-mm2s-sf = <0x1>;
    xlnx,include-s2mm = <0x1>;
    xlnx,include-s2mm-dre = <0x0>;
    xlnx,include-s2mm-sf = <0x1>;
    xlnx,include-sg ;
    xlnx,mm2s-burst-size = <0x10>;
    xlnx,mm2s-scheduler = <0x2>;
    xlnx,num-mm2s-channels = <0x1>;
    xlnx,num-s2mm-channels = <0x8>;
    xlnx,prmry-is-aclk-async = <0x0>;
    xlnx,s2mm-burst-size = <0x10>;
    xlnx,sg-include-stscntrl-strm = <0x0>;
    xlnx,sg-length-width = <0xe>;
    xlnx,sg-use-stsapp-length = <0x0>;
    dma-channel@48020030 {
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
        dma-channels = <0x8>;
        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
        interrupts = <0 36 4 0 52 4 0 53 4 0 54 4 0 55 4 0 56 4 0 57 4 0 58 4>;
        xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
        xlnx,device-id = <0x2>;
    };
};
srio_hier0_srio_hier0_maintenance_hopcount_1: maintenance_hopcount@40000000 {
    clock-names = "s_axi_aclk", "m_axi_aclk";
    clocks = <&misc_clk_2>, <&misc_clk_2>;
    compatible = "xlnx,maintenance-hopcount-1.0";
    reg = <0x40000000 0x8000000>;
};

dma-srio-fpga {
    compatible = "XXXX,dma-srio-fpga";
    #dma-cells = <1>;

    /* The "dmas" property contains pairs with the first of each pair being a reference
       to the DMA IP in the device tree and the second of each pair being the
       channel of the DMA IP. For the AXI DMA IP the transmit channel is always 0 and
       the receive is always 1. For the AXI MCDMA IP the 1ast transmit channel is
       always 0 and receive channels start at 16 since there can be a maximum of 16
       transmit channels. 
       Each name in "dma-names" corresponds to a pair in the dmas property and is just a
       logical name (any but unique) that allows access to the channel. */
      
    //             reference to the DMA IP in the device tree   the channel of the DMA IP
    dmas       = < &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA0        0       // TX   sgdma0
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA0        1       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA1        0       // TX   sgdma 1
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_AXI_DMA_SGDMA1        1       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           0       // TX  mcdma0ch0
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          16       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           1       // TX
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          17       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           2       // TX
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          18       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           3       // TX
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          19       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           4       // TX
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          20       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           5       // TX
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          21       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           6       // TX
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          22       // RX
   
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0           7       // TX
                   &srio_hier0_srio_hier0_axi_mcdma_0          23 >;    // RX

           
    dma-names = "sgDma0Tx",     "sgDma0Rx",     "sgDma1Tx",     "sgDma1Rx",
                "mcDma0Ch00Tx", "mcDma0Ch00Rx", "mcDma0Ch01Tx", "mcDma0Ch01Rx",  
                "mcDma0Ch02Tx", "mcDma0Ch02Rx", "mcDma0Ch03Tx", "mcDma0Ch03Rx",  
                "mcDma0Ch04Tx", "mcDma0Ch04Rx", "mcDma0Ch05Tx", "mcDma0Ch05Rx",  
                "mcDma0Ch06Tx", "mcDma0Ch06Rx", "mcDma0Ch07Tx", "mcDma0Ch07Rx";
           
    srio-maintenance = <&srio_hier0_srio_hier0_maintenance_hopcount_1>;
};
```

As you can see the Device Driver I'm writing uses 3 distinct DMA Slave cells to feed the fourth cell that implements the srio channel.

While initially my device driver declared itself compatible with "xlnx,maintenance-hopcount-1.0", now it is compatible with "XXXX,dma-srio-fpga" and references the srio cell using the srio-maintenance phandle: in the code I retrieve the device_node associated with Xilinx SRIO IP via of_parse_phandle(dev->dev.of_node, "srio-maintenance", 0).

With the new node of DeviceTree named dma-srio-fpga, to access the dma slave channels, I use the dma_request_chan to which I pass the strings "sgDma0Tx", "sgDma0Rx", "sgDma1Tx", "sgDma1Rx",...  (the mcdma are ignored for now)

When channels reserved via dma_request_chan() are no longer needed, I release them with dma_release_channel().

Thanks again!